# F12/devtools like JavaScript in browsers

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I'm mostly a JavaScript developer and I enjoy to explore objects and quickly write new source code via F12/devtools in browsers like Chrome/Firefox. The browsers even allow to set breakpoints and single-step through the code etc.

I search something like that for Blender, but I only found the Python shell, which is more like a "text only" interface. Is there any powerful Blender/Python devtools like JavaScript devtools in browsers?

Comment: Yes, Blender text editor is not perfect. So, instead, you can use any IDE for that such as Visual Studio Code for example. But that requires a little bit of workaround. Do you want me to explain the setup details?

Comment: @YannMasoch Hi Yann, can you debug Blender via VSCode? That would be interesting. I just googled it, found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVDf2VSmRvk
So debugging seems to be possible, but 15minutes configuration for simple debugging, which is done via one F12 key press in the browser :S

Comment: In fact, t's not really possible like you can do in Chrome Dev Tools but you can have the python console for debugging inside VSCode. I'll show you the setup I use for add-ons dev.

Answer (score 3):

## Using an external IDE for Blender dev.

In this example, I am going to show you my setup using **VSCode** on **Win 10**. You can use any other IDE you want and it should also work on Mac and Linux too *(I never tested)*.

### Install Python and put Blender in your environment variables

I won't explain these steps as you can find great and easy tutorials on internet. Also, you can skip this part if you already did this.

You need to install Python in order code for Blender and you need to put Blender in your environment variables in order to launch it directly from your IDE (we'll see that later).

### Create an addons directory

On your computer, wherever you want, simply create a directory called `srcipts` and a sub-directory inside called `addons`.

In my case, my directories are `D:\Dev\Blender\scripts\addons`

[image]

Your script or addon folder will be here as shown on the image. Using a folder to organize your addon is a good practice as you will be able to add sub-folders for libraries, icons and so on.

### Specify the Scripts folder on Blender

Open the `User Preferences` on Blender via `File` menu or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>.

Under `File` tab, complete the `Scripts` path in order to point to the scripts folder we just created before (do not point to addons, just to scripts).

Save the User Preferences and close blender.

[image]

### Open VSCode, start to code and launch Blender

Create your code inside VSCode. In this example, I created a simple script `my_script.py` called **My Hello Addon** that prints **"Hello World!"** when activated using the Operator **my_script.hello**.

[image]

```py
bl_info = {
    "name": "My Hello Addon",
    "description": "",
    "author": "Yann Masoch",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 78, 0),
    "location": "3D View > Tools",
    "warning": "", # used for warning icon and text in addons panel
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy

class MyHelloClass(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "my_script.hello"
    bl_label = "My Hello Script"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        print("Hello world!") # Replace this line by your own code
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyHelloClass)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyHelloClass)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Now, simply type `blender` or `blender.exe` in the terminal to launch Blender.

### Activate the addon

At the first start, you have to activate the addon. Open the `User Preferences` on Blender via `File` menu or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>.

Under `Add-ons` tab, search for our addon `My Hello Addon` and make it active by checking the box.

Save the User Preferences.

*You don't need to do this step every time. Once the addon is registered/activated, this step become optional!*

[image]

### Launch the script

Now, you just have to launch the script we registered as an `operator` by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> and searching for its name.

[image]

On VSCode, `Hello World` will appear in the terminal section.

[image]

The terminal section will show all the outputs from Blender and/or Python to help you to debug your code.

In my code, I decided to register the class as an `operator` (search via <kbd>Space</kbd>) but you can launch it from a `button`, a `menu` or more. You will find addon examples or tutorials on internet.

### Reload your code with F8

Every time you change your code, save it on VSCode and press <kbd>F8</kbd> on Blender. It will reload all the Blender addons such as when Blender is starting.

### That's it!

It looks a bit complicated and long but not really. Most of the steps have to be done only once. If your setup is done, you just need to open Blender from VSCode, update your code and press <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think the biggest win of this answer is to see the `print` output, but you can have the same by `winkey+r`, enter `cmd` and drag blender.exe in there, press enter. But this still is no `sane` debugging environment like F12/devtools, it is not even possible to enter single python code in the terminal for quick testing and there is no GUI introspection into Python objects

Comment: Your welcome. Hope that could help you a bit. Yes, using the `terminal` inside VSCode or using `cmd` is almost the same, it's just faster to have everything at the same place. For a quick testing you can also use the Python Console inside Blender `Shift`+`F4` https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/python_console.html

Comment: I also made a video on using VS Code with the Blender Extension by Jacques Lucke: https://youtu.be/q06-hER7Y1Q